# jQuery Call Function After Image Source Changes

Tags: jquery, image, function, image-resizing

I have a a list of thumbs and one big area where is a big image. If I click on each thumb the source of the big image change according to the thumb that was clicked.

I have also a function for resizing the image that are inside the big area

```
$('#thumbImg').click(function(){
  var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');             
  $('#bigArea img').attr('src',newSrc);
  resizeImage();
});
```

I can get inside the funcion because I have an alert and it is displayed each time I click on a thumb. But I think the problem is because the function reads the widths and height of the previous image. 
Is there any way I can call the function just after the image is changed??

Thanks all

Comment: What is resizeImage doing? why not passing the new width, and height of the image clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Bind the function as a `.load()` handler.

```
$('#thumbImg').click(function() {

    var newSrc = $(this).attr('src'); 

    $('#bigArea img').one('load', resizeImage).attr('src',newSrc);

});
```

*EDIT: Changed to use `.one` so that the handler is removed after a click/load. I think you could also just bind the handler to the `#bigArea img` initially, so it would fire whenever a new image is loaded.*